# getting SIGABRT from trying to populate a table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view that I need to populate with dynamic data.

I did it previously in a separate controller and just copied everything over.

However, this time I keep on getting a SIGABRT error. 
I've found out that it's whenever I include these two line it errors out

```
//  editJobTable.dataSource = self
//  editJobTable.delegate = self
```

Here is my full view controller

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UIViewController{
    fileprivate var presenter: HelloworkJobsEditJobPresenter?

    @IBOutlet weak var editJobTable: UITableView!

    func inject(presenter: HelloworkJobsEditJobPresenter) {
        self.presenter = presenter
    }

    var helloworkJob: HelloworkJob!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        helloworkJob = presenter?.getHelloworkJob()
        editJobTable.dataSource = self
        editJobTable.delegate = self
//        editJobTable.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func tapCloseButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 7
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("\(#line): \(#function) \(indexPath.row)")
        let cellIdentifier = "HelloworkJobsEditJobCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HelloworkJobsEditJobCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of HelloworkJobsEditJobCell.")
        }

        cell.cellLabel.text = "labeltest"
        cell.cellTextField.text = "textfieldtest"
        return cell
    }
}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

Any ideas on why it might be throwing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: editJobTable.dataSource = self
editJobTable.delegate = self plus you need to set it in the storyboard if you are using it. :)

Comment: The error signal greatly to tableview not having a cell registered

Register a cell to tableview as below

self.tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "CustomCellClassName", bundle: Bundle.main), forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")

Comment: Try reconnecting your  @IBOutlet weak var editJobTable: UITableView!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must register the tableView with the cell custom class

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "engineTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"cellID")
```

Or

```
tableView.register(engineTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
```

Comment: I thought thats what this line was doing. `guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HelloworkJobsEditJobCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of HelloworkJobsEditJobCell.")
        }`

Comment: to use that line you must first register the nib or the class

Answer (score 2):

Use like this:

```
extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 7
    }
}

extension HelloworkJobsEditJobViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("\(#line): \(#function) \(indexPath.row)")
        let cellIdentifier = "HelloworkJobsEditJobCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? HelloworkJobsEditJobCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of HelloworkJobsEditJobCell.")
        }

        cell.cellLabel.text = "labeltest"
        cell.cellTextField.text = "textfieldtest"
        return cell
    }
}
```